# Why are my JavaScript objects equal to Proxy {}

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

I am loading a JavaScript `object` between Lightning Components

```
var model = {}
model.user = {}
model.caller = {}
model.caller.name = 'Batman';
model.other = {}
// etc
```

And then into component attributes.

```
<aura:attribute name="model" type="Object" />
<aura:attribute name="caller" type="Object" />

cmp.set("v.model", model);
cmp.set("v.caller", model.caller);
```

Then I use then like this:

```
<lightning:input value="{!v.caller.name }" label="Caller name" />
```

Then I get data back out:

```
model.caller = cmp.get("v.caller");
```

My question is:

Why do my JavaScript object sub-objects sometimes get set to Proxy when I inspect them in the console:

```
caller: Proxy
[[Handler]]: e
[[Target]]: Object
[[IsRevoked]]: false
```

And other times I get the values I expect...

```
caller { name : "Bruce Wayne" }
```

Comment: Proxy just means that Locker Service has wrapped up the element in a Proxy. This is normally "transparent" in most cases. As it stands, this may be an [X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/)-type question. What problems are you encountering that you're hoping to resolve? Why does it matter that it's a Proxy or not?

Comment: Using this stringify `console.log(JSON.stringify(model));` can sometimes help to see what the actual data is.

Comment: I've noticed that I consistently get Proxy when i `console.log` a variable from a `component.get`. Are you saying that yours is inconsistent? As in, from a fresh load, `console.log` behavior is different?

Comment: @sfdcfox it matters because it hinders my ability to debug, and because I want to understand why :)

Comment: @tsalb it seems inconsistent, but that might be just because the `model` travels in and out of components and gets JSON.stringify'd and then JSON.parse'd back again during it's travels...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) is how Locker Service implements security features, which is mentioned in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_proxy.htm):

> When a component creates an intrinsic JavaScript object, Locker Service returns the raw JavaScript object. When Locker Service filters the object, it returns a Proxy object. Some scenarios where Locker Service filters an object and returns a Proxy object are:
>
> - Passing an object to a component in a different namespace.
> - Passing an object from a component on API version less than 40.0 to the method of a component on API version greater than or equal to 40.0.
> - Calling cmp.get() to retrieve an attribute value that you set with the value of a native JavaScript object or array. The object or array isn’t filtered when it’s originally created.

So it has specific rules. If you store something in an attribute, it'll pop back out as a Proxy. If you pass the object via aura:method between API versions, it'll convert to a Proxy. And if you process data from a different namespace, you get a Proxy.

Sometimes things get a little bit borderline, but the point of Proxy is that it attaches a custom security handler to whatever its protecting, so that public and private attributes of whatever it is you're working with won't accidentally expose hidden data. While this is really annoying in practice, its a necessary evil for Lightning to work in a consistently secure manner.

Of course, once you JSON.stringify something, you get back your shiny new JSON string, but it'll be missing any attributes that were filtered out by the Proxy to avoid leaking internal data. Similarly, when you JSON.parse, you'll end up with a native object, but the moment you try to put that data anywhere in protected memory areas (e.g. an attribute), it'll eventually end up as a Proxy when you need to use it later.

Generally speaking, when debugging, you can open the Proxy object and examine the `[[Target]]` attribute. Any publicly available data attributes should appear here. Of course, there's no guarantee, so you might end up needing to process the object with Object.keys, JSON.stringify, for(key in obj), and other techniques.

I've found that Object.keys seems to be the most reliable:

```
var obj = component.get("v.attr");
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => console.log(obj[key]));
```

If you really want to avoid working with Proxy, you can probably just set your bundle version to 39.0. Locker Service only really protects 40.0 components and up.

Comment: so to get a native JavaScript object I need to JSON.stringify and then JSON.parse again? or is there a cleaner approach?

Comment: @Robs For debugging purposes, yes, you most likely would want to either stringify/parse or use the Object.keys method I suggested to get a list of values. Maybe modify it somehow.