# What type of object is passed to lightning/empApi callback?

Tags: lightning-web-components, change-data-capture

The main question is - why do I have to do this in callback (I mean JSON transormations)

```
 subscribe(this.channel, -1, response=> {
            /// main hook
            let payload = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(response)).data.payload;
    })
```

Is there the far more simlpe way to get payload object?

Comment: You don't need to do this. Simply saying `response.data.payload` should suffice. What happens when you try this?

Answer (score 0):

As for your question:

> What type of object is passed to lightning/empApi callback?

With a quick test, I can see that the object type received in the callback when you subscribe to an event is a **JavaScript [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)** object.

And the reason why you need to stringify and parse it as JSON is very well explained in **[this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/222366/54851)** by none other than [sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox).