# How to get row when iterating over aura attribute in controller

Tags: aura-attribute

here is what i am trying to do

CMP

```
<aura: attribute name= "list" type=CustomObj[]/>
```

Controller

```
var list = component.get("v.list");
var FinalList=[];
//iterating over list
for (var i in list){
If (list[i].Name==``){
FinalList.push(list[i]);
Console.log('Current Row', list[i]);// prints proxy {} in console.

}

}
```

If condition met i just want to access that row & push into another attribute if same type  .No idea what I am missing but list[i] doesn't give me row whereas list[i].Field working fine. Need help.
Thanks

Comment: <aura: attribute name= "list" type=CustomObj[ ]/>

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code. Perhaps what intrigues you is why proxy is logged. This is because of the locker service. Please read more here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_proxy.htm .You can access the elements like you usually do by `list[i].Name` or any other attribute you want to access. If you want you can use `for i` loop or `foreach` loop.

Comment: A better way to do it would be to use `array.filter`, make it more readable. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 1):

You can read more about [Proxy](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/222343/2984); it doesn't stop your access, it just makes debugging a little more of an annoyance. As an aside, an easier way to make your list would be as follows:

```
var finalList = component.get("v.list").filter(row=>(!!row.Name));
```